# Creating dynamic variables based on len of list/array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list

I am trying to write a program that runs a command on Cisco router and writes list of IP on a text file. I am able to write all IPs to the file and then grab all IPs successfully.  Now the part where I am having trouble is that I do not know how many IPs I will get from the list.  As I would like to compare each IP I get from file against user's defined IP, I would like a way to either create dynamic variable based on # of IPs or somehow iterate through all IPs and compare it against user's IP.

```
import re
import ipaddr

userIP = raw_input('Enter IP address to compare i.e, 10.10.10.0/24:')
ipFile = ("router.com.txt")
found = []
with open(ipFile, 'r') as f:
    for text in f.readlines()[1:]: #File had a blank line so this skips it
        text = text.rstrip()
        regex = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
        #print regex
        found.append(regex)
    print found
    print len(found) - 1
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
[['10.10.20.192/27'], ['10.10.40.0/24'], []]
2
```

Now the hard part where I am struggling is how can I compare each of these with variable **userIP** dynamically.

```
#if userIP.overlaps(found):
#print "Overlapping IPs!!"
#else:
#print "Does not Overlap!!"
```

Thanks
Damon

Comment: It looks like you can use the built-in [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.compare_networks) library if you are using Python 3.3+. However, for Py2.7 there is a backport package you can still use: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress

Comment: I am using ipaddr.py and it is working fine for me.  I need help with dynamic variable part

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic variables"?

Comment: I am new to programming so that was the first thing that popped up in my mind.  Since list length is dynamic I couldn't think a way other than dynamically assigning creating IP and assigning them all IPs.  If there is a better way I will use it

Comment: Damon: Most containers, like lists and dictionaries, are mutable, which means their contents can be altered at almost any time. To me a "dynamic variable" is one the program creates **and names** at runtime—which is generally considered a bad idea and can generally be avoided by using a mutable container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare each IP address with the user input subnet one by one like this (and it actually uses less memory than your code):

```
import re

userIP = raw_input('Enter IP address to compare i.e, 10.10.10.0/24:')
userIP = pseudoSubnetClass(userIP)     # pseudo code
ipFile = ("router.com.txt")
found = []
with open(ipFile, 'r') as f:
    for text in f: #File had a blank line so this skips it
        text = text.rstrip()
        match = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
        if not match:
            continue
        found = match[0]
        if userIP.overlaps(found):     # This part is
            print "Overlapping IPs!!"  # pseudo code too
            break
    else:
        print "Does not Overlap!!"
```

Comment: I edited the code as it is if userIP.overlaps(found): instead of if subnet.overlaps(found):  Also, I am getting this:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'overlaps'

Comment: @Damon you said you are using `ipaddr.py`. The conditional test is actually your pseudo code. Do you want me to change that to use `ipaddress`?

Comment: Conditional test is actually works (ipaddr.py).  For example:  if userIP.overlaps(found):    I hardcoded userIP and found variables and it worked as it suppose to.

Comment: @Damon: the `userIP` is input through `raw_input` and it must be a `str`. Did you use that value to create an object later somewhere?

Comment: That is the end plan but for faster testing I hardcoded it:  userIP = "10.10.10.0/24"

Comment: @Damon for faster testing you can just use `if userIP == found`. But it won't take care of things like "10.10.10.0/24" vs "10.10.10.0/25".

Comment: Yea, I need to take care of "10.10.10.0/24" vs "10.10.10.0/25".  Not sure what this error is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'overlaps'.  I know this works if I hard code the values.  Can it be it is looking for something like found[0] etc?

Comment: @Damon: your `userIP` is a `str` which doesn't include the `overlaps` method. You have to use whatever class you used before to decorate the value.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  It is looking for input with '' around IP ('10.10.10.0/24').  Is there any way I can add '' around ip stored in found variable?

Comment: @Damon: I'm confused by the quotes you used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid a lot of complexity once you take into account that `re.findall` will pull out all IPs over all lines of the file itself, you don't need to have your own loop. For example:

```
import re

userIP = raw_input('Enter IP address to compare i.e, 10.10.10.0/24:')
ipFile = "router.com.txt"

with open(ipFile) as f:
    for ip in re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\/(?:[\d]{1,3})', f.read()):
        if overlaps(ip, userIP):
            print "Overlapping IPs!!"
            break
```

The `overlaps()` function is just a made up example, to help illustrate the rest of the logic.

Comment: @Philip Tzou and your solution worked after I fixed an obvious issue.  Can you tell me which one is a better solution to use?  This list won't grow more than 10 IPs usually but I might use this for future project.  Which one is more efficient?  Thanks all for helping  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want?

Change `append` to `extend` so that the resulting list is something like `['10.10.20.192/27', '10.10.40.0/24', '']`.

```
found.extend(regex)
```

Ask whether `userIP` matches any of those found:

```
if userIP in found:
    <suite>
```